# In XML PARSE using COBOL the FUNCTION LENGTH (XML-TEXT) calculating 1 for XML-TEXT = blanks

Tags: xml-parsing, cobol

I am trying to parse an XML document in COBOL using XML PARSE, one segment at a time. In the CONTENT-CHARACTERS check I am doing COMPUTE WS-XML-LEN = FUNCTION LENGTH (XML-TEXT).

There are some START OF ELEMENT for which I do not want to process, for them also it is going into the CONTENT-CHARACTERS check and calculating the length of (XML-TEXT) = 1 even though the XML-TEXT is blank.

Could you let me know what could be the reason and I should modify in my program.

Comment: Can you show your code and sample data?

Comment: Maybe the CONTENT-CHARACTERS consists of a single space character, at which point the length is correct.

Answer (score 1):

FUNCTION LENGTH (xyz) gives you the length OF THE FIELD, not the "length" of the DATA. COBOL has no "string delimiter" (except for a special use for a literal).

If xyz is PIC X(30) it will return 30 "every time", irrespective of the content of the field.

You haven't mentioned which compiler or operating system you are using, but if you are using an IBM Cobol, you should produce the "LIST" output (the generated pseudo-assembler code). You will see that the code generated for FUNCTION LENGTH ( something ) is just an MVC from the "literal pool" which will be pointing at a constant value which is the same as the length of your field, and which is (likely) only there because you are using FUNCTION LENGTH.

The LENGTH OF "special register" is similar, if you have it.

If you want to know if a field is all blank:

```
IF something EQUAL TO SPACES
```

If you need to know the length of a field given that you know a specific "trailing" or "leading" value (spaces, zero, low-values, whatever) then you have to write some code to do it.

For counting data and ignoring trailing spaces, a common way us to use FUNCTION REVERSE and then INSPECT ... TALLYING ... FOR LEADING SPACE. There are other ways.

You'll need the length of the field (to calculate the length of the data) but *the length of the field is invariant* so only calculate (FUNCTION LENGTH or plain LENGTH OF) once.

There is a subtle difference between FUNCTION LENGTH and LENGTH OF, which probably won't affect your task.

Comment: What you are saying here is generally true for variables declared in a source program. XML-TEXT is a little different. Its length is set based on the content parsed from the XML document. See [XML-TEXT](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/igy3lr31/1.3.8.19?ACTION=MATCHES&REQUEST=xml+parse&TYPE=FUZZY&SHELF=&DT=20060329140556&CASE=&searchTopic=TOPIC&searchText=TEXT&searchIndex=INDEX&rank=RANK&ScrollTOP=FIRSTHIT#FIRSTHIT). This being the case: `COMPUTE WS-XML-LEN = FUNCTION LENGTH (XML-TEXT)` should give the number of characters parsed from the document.

Comment: Thanks NealB. Variable-length data is the only time LENGTH OF/FUNCTION LENGTH will do a calculation at "run time". With other variable-length fields (VARYING ON, OCCURS ... DEPENDING ON) we already know the length :-) I think it is the same problem, and relating to your comment to the TS/OP, LENGTH OF/FUNCTION LENGTH are working on the length of the field, even if variable, not the length of the data. One space is one space, in a (varibale-length) field of one byte.